# Singular matrix error as a single function but not when run piece wise

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Why am I getting a singular error when I run it as a function, but when it was done piece wise before it worked correctly? Using the same matrices for both. Following along from a video and I am not able to see what I did different when looking though what he did.

```
#Artificial data for learning purpose provided by Alex
X= [
    [148, 24,1385],
    [132,25,2031],
    [453,11,86],
    [158,24,185],
    [172,25,201],
    [413,11,86],
    [38,54,185],
    [142,25,431],
    [453,31,86]
]
    
X = np.array(X)

# Add in the bias (default) value of car before calculating features. 
ones = np.ones(X.shape[0])
X = np.column_stack([ones, X])

# y values provided by Alex
y = [10000,20000,15000,20050,10000,20000,15000,25000,12000]

XTX = X.T.dot(X)
XTX_inv = np.linalg.inv(XTX)
w_full = XTX_inv.dot(X.T).dot(y)

# bias value
w0 = w_full[0]
# features
w = w_full[1:]
print(w0, w)
#Output: 25844.754055766753, array([ -16.08906468, -199.47254894,   -1.22802883])
```

At this point the code runs as expected. However, this function gives an error:

```
# Error in function
def train_linear_regression(X, y):
    ones = np.ones(X.shape[0])
    X = np.column_stack([ones, X])

    XTX = X.T.dot(X)
    XTX_inv = np.linalg.inv(XTX)
    w = XTX_inv.dot(X.T).dot(y)
    
    return w[0], w[1:]

w0, w = train_linear_regression(X, y)
print(w0, w)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-ed5d7ddc40b1> in <module>
----> 1 train_linear_regression(X,y)

2 frames
<__array_function__ internals> in inv(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     86 
     87 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 88     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     89 
     90 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are adding/stacking bias (`ones`) to `X` twice. First with in the normal flow and second time within the function, that is leading to determinant of `0` for the matrix `XTX` in the function.

So you need to remove the addition of `ones` from one of them.

```
def train_linear_regression(X, y):
    ones = np.ones(X.shape[0]) 
    X = np.column_stack([ones, X]) # stacking ones here again - REMOVE
....
```